# Two types of options values in select

Tags: php, html, loops

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT city.id as city_id,city.city_name,locality.id,locality.area_name  ".
               "FROM city, locality  ".
               "WHERE city.id = locality .city_id order by city_id"); 
$previous = '';

while($rss=mysql_fetch_object($r)) { ?>

    <?php if (empty($previous) || $previous != $rss->city_id) { ?>

        <legend><?=$rss->city_name?></legend>

    <?php } ?> 

    <?php $previous = $rss->city_id; ?>

    <input type="checkbox" name="sub_type[]" id="sub_type" value="<?=$rss->id?>" />

    <span><?=$rss->area_name?></span><br/>

<?php

}

?>
```

this is my city name and area name record listing down in check box now i want show same thing in select box with city name in red color and then its child area name its little example is on http://www.99acres.com/  as city display on this site

Comment: Please reformat your code for better readability

Answer (score 0):

Without writing the code for you, you should be able to adapt this code to fit your needs.

```
<select name="SELECTNAME">
<?php while($rss=mysql_fetch_object($r)) {
         echo '<option value="' . $value . '" ';
              if () { // Put your if statement code here for when you want the option to be coloured red.
                  echo 'YOUR RED CLASS';
              }
         echo '>' . $name . '</option>';
     }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: ok now how can i control this in search . if(isset($_REQUEST['city'])) { $city = $_REQUEST['city']; if($city != '') { $pwhere .=" AND u.city = '".$city."'"; } } this is my AND query. How can i manage this query if user select area in dropdown list? as if user select area than and query found no record and found 0 record

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want:

```
$r=mysql_query("SELECT city.id as city_id,city.city_name,locality.id,locality.area_name  ".
               "FROM city, locality  ".
               "WHERE city.id = locality .city_id order by city_id"); 
$previous = '';
?>
<select name="foo">
<?php while($rss=mysql_fetch_object($r)) { ?>
    <?php if (empty($previous) || $previous != $rss->city_id) { ?>
        <option name="city[]" style="color:red" value="<?=$rss->city_name?>"><?=$rss->city_name?></option>
    <?php } ?> 
    <?php $previous = $rss->city_id; ?>
    <option name="sub_type[]" id="sub_type" value="<?=$rss->id?>"><?=$rss->area_name?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: yes but my question is about this if(isset($_REQUEST['city']))
  {
   $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
   if($city != '')
   {
    $pwhere .=" AND  u.city = '".$city."'";
   }
  }  this is my AND query. How can i manage this query if user select area in dropdown list? as if user select area than and query found no record and found 0 record

Comment: how to use <option name="city[]"> <option name="sub_type[]">   for getiing this value using post or request method  for using this value in sql query ?